# Laravel 8 - What is the best way to retrieve large amounts of data for a REST API without running out of memory?

Tags: php, laravel, rest, optimization

I was wondering what would be a good way to retrieve large amounts (20000+ rows) of data with Laravel 8.

I'm working with a Laravel 8 REST API. One of the endpoints (when unfiltered) gets all the rows in a table, along with some model relations. Then, we have an Angular app that uses all of that data and transforms it into an Excel file for the client to use.

The problem is, the database keeps growing and growing, and if our client wants to download the whole table, the app runs out of memory.

For example

```
if($request->has('country_id')) {
        $users->where('country_id', $request->country_id);
    }

return $users->with($relations)->get(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email' ...]);
```

Assuming the request sometimes needs the whole table unfiltered, what would be a better way to approach sending a lot of data over a REST API?

Thanks!

Comment: Create file in backend with use of [chunk](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#chunking-results) method.

Comment: Does it have to be an xlsx file or would a csv file work? xlsx is harder to produce in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

1. you should use pagination.
2. other than you can use `->toBase()`, it will reduce memory dramatically.
3. if you want to work with many rows and don't need all columns probably, you can use `->select` to select proper columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to handle this would be utilizing Laravel's [Lazy Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#lazy-collections), or maybe even [Cursors](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#cursors). You can then paginate or do whatever you want in your Angular app. Make sure you are only pulling out the attributes you want in the call. e.g using a cursor:

```php
$users = $request->has('country_id')) ?
  User::cursor()
    ->filter( function($user) use ( $request->country_id ){
        return $user->country_id === $request->country_id
    })
    ->pluck('id', 'first_name','last_name', 'email' ) : 
  null;
```

If you are needing to load relations, then you'll need to use a Lazy Collection.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you shouldn't do it all at once. You will run out of memory in no time at all when the database is growing.

One method you may try is to chunk the data and write it as CSV format or whatever format you want to in chunk basis. Then after all of the data is processed then you can download it. I will create a downloadable file from my backend if I were you.

With that method you will never run out of memory

To chunk your result, you can see this documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#chunking-results

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement one of the laravel cache driver.

> [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache)

You can also use Chunking in Query and also on Collection.

> [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-chunk)